# how to import aws-sdk to tsx file in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I used typescript ( tsx ) for react . In upload image task , I used aws-sdk to upload to server s3 . I also installed aws-sdk by npm and typings .

**UploadFile.tsx**

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
//constant
import DefaultValue from '../../Constants/DefaultValue';

AWS.config.update({
    region: DefaultValue.REGION,
    credentials: new AWS.Credentials(DefaultValue.ACCESS_KEY_ID, DefaultValue.SECRET_KEY)
});

class UploadFile extends React.Component<any,any> {
    s3: any;
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2016-11-07'});
    }

}
```

Chrome console error : 'AWS is undefined' .
how can i import AWS ? thanks for help .

Comment: react-js is for frontend. You're going to put ACCESS_KEY_ID and SECRET_KEY into the frontend. Are you sane? :)

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser oh I knew it's risk . But it's my private website . It just use in local .

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to actually have the aws-sdk package bundled in, or avoid using an import entirely.

If you go the Webpack route and bundle in your dependency, you can [read about that here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/webpack.html). You'll need to `npm install -S aws-sdk` and use a loader from TypeScript like ts-loader or awesome-typescript-loader.

If you want to continue using a script tag, then you'll have to write something like the following:

```
import * as _AWS from "aws-sdk";
declare var AWS: typeof _AWS;
```

Where the import for `_AWS` itself will be removed (since you'll have only used it for its types), and then you'll just refer to `AWS` as you otherwise would.